# How to validate fields properly in Struts 2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here :

```mxl
<validators>
    <field name="cli.idCli" >
        <field-validator type="requiredString" short-circuit="true">
            <message>Required field (*)</message>
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="stringlength">
            <param name="minLength">8</param>
             <param name="maxLength">8</param>
             <message>ID must has 8 characters</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

because, actually i'm getting this error:

> ERROR
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager 
>   Caught exception while loading file
>   .../action/ServiceAction-findPets-validation.xml Invalid validation
>   type: requiredString - field-validator

Also, I would like to know if doing ajax calls (and sending JSON data) I can validate the existence of these data ? I mean through .xml validators. Moreover, if I implement  `Validateable` interface, each time that a request arrives to this action this method is going to be triggered? Is there a way to specify for which action methods is it?

Answer (score 1):

The name is case sensitive, you should use

```mxl
<field-validator type="requiredstring" short-circuit="true">
```

The data can be validated after it's populated to the action. Either  you do it in a *declarative* way using `*-validation.xml` or *programmatically* via `validate()`.

You can configure `validation` interceptor to choose between these two ways, because by default `validate()` runs after declarative validations are done even if they are short-circuit.

Consider using `alwaysInvokeValidate` parameter. If you use *aliased* validation files as `ActionClass-alias-validation.xml` then validations are run for this action alias only. You can use this alias when you map your action methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna skip validation to any action method use `@SkipValidation` annotation.

```
@SkipValidation
public String yourMethod {
    ...         
    return "input";
}
```