# Validation of struts using xml file not working

Tags: java, xml, validation, jsp, struts2

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
         <title>Add new product</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:form action="emp1" method="post">
            <s:textfield label="Name" name="name" ></s:textfield>
            <s:textfield label="Age" name="age" ></s:textfield>     
            <s:submit value="Save" align="left"></s:submit>     
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">

    <display-name>DemoValidation</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>    
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="emp1" class="controller.Employee">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>            
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**Employee.java**

```
package controller;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Employee extends ActionSupport{

    private String ename;
    private int age;

    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getEname() {
        return ename;
    }
    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Employee-validation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd"

<validators>

    <field name="ename">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>Name is required</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="age">          
        <field-validator type="int">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <param name="min">21</param>
            <param name="max">40</param>
            <message>Age should be between 21 to 40</message>
        </field-validator>      
    </field>

 </validators>
```

I have used the above code in order to demonstrate the validation for struts2. The validation is not triggered , even if the validate fails , success page gets displayed. Kindly go through the code and suggest me the changes.

Comment: Where did you put your Employee-validation.xml file?

Comment: in the same folder where my Employee.java is present

Comment: Which S2 version ? You should use the new filter, [FilterDispatcher is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17103563/1654265).

Comment: Make sure that it is deployed also in the same location.

Comment: @user3678383 You should read more about how to trigger validation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25030487/573032

Comment: @AndreaLigios i made the changes , still facing same issue

Comment: @AleksandrM both are deployed at same location

Comment: @RomanC i gone through the link , still issue not resolved

Comment: Debug your app. Turn the `struts.devMode` on. Follow Andrea advice.

Comment: @Aleksandr I changed the filter. Now the validation is running for age but not for name.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thank you so much. But apart from age no other field is validating like i tried for email as well. And i cross checked all the typos as well. Still facing the issue.

Comment: @user3678383 I've gone through your code and have given you suggestions, if the problem is not resolved, I won't answer because no benefit to do it neither  of my suggestions doesn't work for you.

Comment: @user3678383 If you want to thank me so much, why not upvoting the linked answer as suggested ? That's the way you say *thanks* on StackOverflow ;) P.S: I've just realized you've never voted anything. To vote up, simply press the arrow up in the top left corner of an answer (or a question).

Answer (score 2):

1. Apply the new filter because the [`FilterDispatcher` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103563/1654265);
2. Change your wrong definition from

   ```xml
   <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator Definition 1.0.3//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-definition-1.0.3.dtd">
   ```

   to

   ```xml
   <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
       "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
       "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
   ```

As you can see in the Apache directory (http://struts.apache.org/dtds/) there are **xwork-validator** `1.0`, `1.0.2`, `1.0.3` but **xwork-validator-definition** is only `1.0`, and is not the right one, according to [the documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html#Validation-DefiningValidationRules).

Comment: Very weird. Can you please edit your question by updating the code according to the modification made ? DTD, new Filter etc... even if minified and with name changed, the code must be the same of your real code, otherwise you could avoid posting something critical to the problem without noticing. Also pay attention to constructors (there must always be a no-args one, implicit or, when another is specified, explicit) and getters/setters for variables with one letter lowercase and another capitalized eg "fBar" that Eclipse creates in a wrong way

Comment: Will do it and let u know

Comment: Andrea Ligios i have made the edits as suggested by you. Please go through it.

Comment: In JSP it is still name, not ename