# Struts2 development error for email validation

Tags: xml, struts2

I am trying use struts2 validation but it could not work can i know why is development error for the validation. The codes is below

```
  <field name="myEmail">
      <field-validator type="email">
         <message>Must provide a valid email</message>
      </field-validator>
  </field>
```

Comment: What a development error?

Comment: it states not properly configured. i not sure why the problem arises as i did all same only i changed filed name to my own object name with propertiers likes xVO.name

Comment: properties like xVO.name are NOT good to Struts2 because the first word is composed by only one letter and the getters/setters are misinterpreted. Try using a word of at least two letter as first word for your variables, or write the getters yoursefl with getXVO instead of getxVO

Comment: @jakerobert The field name should correspond to the bean property which is validated. See [how to validate fields properly in struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25030487/573032)